# .ASP controller code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mvc, controller

I've tried to create application with MVC N-layer pattern. I asked my buddy for a shot review, and he said, "You should separate logic from controller".
But my controller only work as a `ViewModel` creator. I'm sure I must not create `ViewModel` from `BusinessLayer`.  I need to pass data in DTO like I did here. But what about logic that takes data from DTO and puts it in `ViewModel` with some rules? I completely misunderstand and need assistance.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var uploadedImages = UploadedImageHandler.GetAllUploadedImages();
        var model = new IndexViewModel(uploadedImages);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void SetDescription(string description, int id)
    {
        UploadedImageHandler.SetDescription(description, id);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var result = UploadedImageHandler.UploadFile(file);
        JsonResult json;

        if (result != null)
        {
            var uploadImageViewModel = new UploadedImagesViewModel
            {
                Compression = result.Compression,
                DateTime = result.DateTime.HasValue ? result.DateTime.Value.ToString("f") : null,
                Description = result.Description ?? "",
                ExifVersion = result.ExifVersion,
                ExposureTime = result.ExposureTime,
                GpsLatitude = result.GpsLatitude,
                GpsLongitude = result.GpsLongitude,
                ImagePath = result.ImagePath,
                Manufacturer = result.Manufacturer,
                Model = result.Model,
                UploadedImageId = result.UploadedImageId
            };
            var uploadResult = new UploadResultViewModel
            {
                Preview = new PreviewViewModel {Id = result.UploadedImageId, PreviewPath = result.PreviewPath},
                UploadedImage = uploadImageViewModel
            };
            json = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = uploadResult,
                ContentType = "text/html"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            json = new JsonResult
            {
                ContentType = "text/html"
            };
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*You should separate logic from controller*"

Honestly if a colleague said that to me then I would immediately say.  *Great thanks.  What do you think I could move out and why*.

It's great to offer feedback but generic feedback like that for me was never useful and I personally always prefer specific help to follow.

Looking at that code it doesn't look like you any logic there to play with, so unless he is meaning the Model -> ViewModel mapping then yes, you could move that to a Mapping layer but I don't consider that a necessity.  If you were considering that the code would probably benefit from using a tool such as [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to achieve this.

#### Using AutoMapper

The trick here is you define your mapping rules in the AutoMapper configuration so they can be reused whenever you need to map X -> Y.

```
public JsonResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var result = UploadedImageHandler.UploadFile(file);

    if(result == null)
    {
        return new JsonResult { ContentType = "text/html" };
    }

        // Assuming ResultModel is the class type for result
    var uploadResult = Mapper.Map<UploadResultViewModel, ResultModel>(result);

    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = uploadResult,
        ContentType = "text/html"
    };  
}
```

#### Not using AutoMapper

No mapping framework with If statements inverted to reduce nesting as well as remove need for additional variables.

```
public JsonResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var result = UploadedImageHandler.UploadFile(file);

    if(result == null)
    {
        return new JsonResult { ContentType = "text/html" };
    }

    var uploadImageViewModel = new UploadedImagesViewModel
    {
        Compression = result.Compression,
        DateTime = result.DateTime.HasValue ? result.DateTime.Value.ToString("f") : null,
        Description = result.Description ?? "",
        ExifVersion = result.ExifVersion,
        ExposureTime = result.ExposureTime,
        GpsLatitude = result.GpsLatitude,
        GpsLongitude = result.GpsLongitude,
        ImagePath = result.ImagePath,
        Manufacturer = result.Manufacturer,
        Model = result.Model,
        UploadedImageId = result.UploadedImageId
    };

    var uploadResult = new UploadResultViewModel
    {
        Preview = new PreviewViewModel 
        {   
            Id = result.UploadedImageId, 
            PreviewPath = result.PreviewPath 
        },
        UploadedImage = uploadImageViewModel
    };

    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = uploadResult,
        ContentType = "text/html"
    };  
}
```